# PySimpleGui FileBrowse and FolderBrowse dialogs look different after conversion to .exe file

Tags: python-3.x, py2exe, pysimplegui

I built a GUI application for Windows using:

- Python 3.4.0
- PySimpleGUI 4.0.0
- Py2exe to create the .exe file

However when I run the application by running the .exe file, the **FileBrowse** and **FolderBrowse dialogs** of PySimpleGUI **look different** than running the application direcly from the script.

- Does anyone know why the dialogs showup differently?
- How can this behavior be avoided?

What I expect is that also the file and folder browse elements I used look the same after conversion to an .exe file.

[FolderBrowse dialog when I run my application from the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjPUW.png)

[FolderBrowse dialog when running the .exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60XGs.png)

Comment: I just tried using PyInstaller and the dialog boxes were the same for my short program with .py and .exe runs.  This has to be a tkinter / Py2exe interaction problem.  I would search for tkinter and py2exe to see what others have to say about it or how they did or didn't get around it.

Comment: Hi MikeyB, thanks for your input. I tried PyInstaller right now and however using PyInstaller I get the same different looking dialog windows. As it does work in your case, using these .exe files from Python seem not too stable to use then.